# How to run a function on a console event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I would like to emulate my programs terminal results on my local web server, but I dont know how to get the info from the terminal. My guess is im looking for a listener or console event but I havent found anything yet for it. I need to run a function and get the terminal data everytime a input, log, warn, error, ect... happends.

Comment: Look for Process Standard Output Redirection, and put it in a WebSocket or SSE stream to the remote client. You'll need to buffer/batch-up output to avoid being unnecessarily chatty.

Comment: Basically, this: https://github.com/drag0s/node-websocketd